# Searching in an ArrayList from simple POJO class and avoiding null values using java 8 stream

Tags: java, spring, collections

I have an **ArrayList** class having name **MainList**

Like

```
 public class MainList{

 private String sname;
 private String lname;
 private String address;
 private String branch;
 private String city;

//getter and setter
}
```

Also I have another pojo class based on values in this class I will perform searching of Lname, address, branch and city.. its **Search**

```
public class Search{

private String searchSname;

//getter and setter
}
```

I used following code to perform search

```
List<MainList> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//injecting bean to insert data
Search search=new search();
//injecting bean ti insert data
List<MainList> data = myList.stream()
.filter(p-> p.getSname().equals(search.getSearchSname()))
.findFirst()
.orElse(null);
```

This works fine if search.getSearchSname() contain any value but **I want to make senario in which if the value of search.getSearchSname()  is null then instead of returning nullPointerException it will return first object of MainList otherwise perform search operation based on value**

As I show you a very simple example but I want to implement it in very large data and there is possibility that some of the inputs are not given and I required to skip it while filtering I  can implement it by if condition but if any scope beyond that then plz help me  ...

Comment: What if myList is null?  Or if it's empty?  What if myList is not empty but contains null elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a null check to your filter:

```
MainList firstMatch = myList.stream()
        .filter(p -> search.getSearchSname() == null
                || p.getSname().equals(search.getSearchSname()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MainList> myList = new ArrayList<>();
Search search = new search();
List<MainList> data;

if (search.getSearchSname() == null) {
    data = myList.get(0);
} else {
    data = myList.stream()
        .filter(p-> p.getSname().equals(search.getSearchSname()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```